# When i run my android code the my code gives this error....."java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick"

Tags: java, android

this is my android code when we run application and it is automatically close when login method is call on the clicking of the button

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: soubhagya.hostinger, PID: 25611
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
>   android:onClick at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640) 
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455) 
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a
>   null object reference
>   at soubhagya.hostinger.Login.logIn(Login.java:51)
>   at soubhagya.hostinger.Login.radhaJi(Login.java:106)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640) 
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455) 
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)

Here's the Login activity.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    //web url string
    public static final String LOGIN_URL="http://abhinavin.000webhostapp.com/userregistration/login.php";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL="email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS="success";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME="tech";
    public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF ="email";
    public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF="loggedin";
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button btn_SignIn;
    private boolean loggedIn=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        //this is text fields
        editTextEmail=findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextPassword=findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_SignIn=findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

    }
    //End of onCreate method
this login method is call on the click of button

    private void logIn() {
        //error is in this line i think.
        //get value of email from edit text
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        //get value of password from edit text
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            //override the onResponse method
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                 //check condition
                if (response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(LOGIN_SUCCESS)) {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Login.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);

                    editor.putBoolean(EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, Boolean.parseBoolean(email));
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            //overridre getParams
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> prams=new HashMap<>();
                //put the data in map
                prams.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                prams.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                //return prams
                return prams;
            }


        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
End of login method

    //overtide the onResume method
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //get SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn=sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF ,false);
        if(loggedIn)
        {
            //set Intent object
            Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
            //StartActivity
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    //this is onclick function
    public void btn_Click(View view) {
        //call login function
        logIn();

    }
}
```

xml code in this code edit text and button are defined

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="soubhagya.hostinger.Login">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3" android:hint="Emile"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4" android:hint="Password"/>
<Button
        android:text="Signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="btn_Click"
/></LinearLayout>
```

this is my xml code in whis we can design ui of our application

Comment: share you xml layout with question

Comment: ok just wait a min

Comment: this is my xml code

Comment: now i add the xml file

Comment: The error message you've given doesn't really line up with the code and XML you've posted. Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: Check all of the `R.id`s you're passing in the `findViewById()` calls against the `id`s in the layout. They don't match.

Comment: Please do null checking at `editTextEmail.getText()` and `editTextPassword.getText()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should change to `btn_Click` in your xml

from `android:onClick="radhaJi"`

to  `android:onClick="btn_Click"`.

2. Your button initialize wrong id

   ```
   btn_SignIn=findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
   ```

should be

```
 btn_SignIn=findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

Comment: i change this but still it not working

Comment: throw same error

Comment: answer edited..

Comment: not working.....

Comment: not working mean ? same error ?

Comment: yes........................

Comment: please correct your two textView id too

Comment: thanx sir its working

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

You need implement the `View.OnClickListener` along with your `Activity` like the following.

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btn_signup)
            logIn();
    }
}
```

And change the layout to look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Emile"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Signin" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: not working from this

Comment: Have you tried with the updated answer?

Comment: yes but still not]

Comment: Please see the updated answer and change your layout as suggested.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: this error is come from    private void login() {
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        Log.i("program","yha tk");
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();

Comment: You have accepted an answer. So I think the problem is solved now.